# Xcode caching issue

Tags: xcode4, uiviewcontroller, subclass

A few days I created a class for my iOS project. It was a subclass of UIViewController. I wanted to use it programmatically only, without a XIB file.

As I wanted to present it as modal viewController, the screen flashed to black and my view wasn't presented.

After some research I decided to delete the class and start all over again and use a XIB this time, because I know it would be easier.

Of cause I called the class the same. But swoosh, the same error occurred again. I then deleted it, created a new one and named it deferent. Everything is fine.

So every time I give a class the old name, the same old problem occurs again.

I tried deleting the derived data, opened the xcodeproj to delete everything except the pbxproj file, I searched the class name using grep (no hits) I deleted the app from my iPad (the same with the simulator), the ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ directory I removed every reference to my app from every file and restarted the computer.

Nothing worked. It seems as my Class Name is now black listed and leads to a general "don't-work-error"…

Sure. I can simple rename it. But this behavior shows me that something must be wrong.

Thanks for any help – Julian

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's really annoying and is totally Xcode's fault. The solution that works for me is to remove DerivedData folder which you can find at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. Hope this helps.

Comment: My DerivedData folder is stored relative to the project. I configured Xcode so that I can remove it faster. So I already tried it :) It's a while ago but as I remember, I just renamed the class…